# How to control reading of bits in XOR data frames?

Tags: binary, tcl, xor

I'm trying to learn to read the XOR data frames used in web sockets in Tcl.

I was reading the HTTP requests using:

```
chan configure $sock -buffering line -blocking 0 -encoding iso8859-1 -translation crlf
chan event $sock readable [list ReadLine $sock]
[catch {chan gets $sock line} len]
```

Now after the socket is opened, `chan configure $sock -translation binary` to read the component bits of the XOR frame, but I'm confused about the `-buffering` and `-buffersize`
and I changed the `chan event` to not get a full line but `chan read numChars`; but the `readable` event seems to fire for every character or again after each character is read.

Should the various segments of bits be read directly from the channel or should larger pieces be read from the channel into variables and then the bits separated from those pieces?

What is the proper channel configuration in order to read the bits in a controlled manner?

Also, it reads here https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/chan.html#M35 that in non-blocking mode `chan read` may not read all the requested characters. What is to be done? Count them and read again until get them all?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-buffering` and `-buffersize` are options used to manage the output side of the channel, i.e., when you write data to the socket with `puts` (or `chan puts`; it's an alternate name for the same thing). They're not used for input.

When you have the channel in binary mode, the characters you read and write correspond one-to-one with the bytes. You probably shouldn't use `gets` (`chan gets`) on binary data; `read` (`chan read`) is more likely to be appropriate. (For writing, the `-nonewline` option to `puts` is virtually mandatory.)

When you `read` a non-blocking channel with a number of characters/bytes requested, you can get *up to* that amount of data. If the request can be satisfied with what is in the read buffer, that is used and no request to the underlying file descriptor is done. If the request can be partially satisfied with buffered data, that's used first and only then is a request done for more data; if that request produces more data than needed, it is stored in the buffer (you can see how much with `chan pending`, but that's not normally important for binary channels). However, if that one non-blocking request does not deliver enough data to give you what you asked for, `read` returns anyway: you have a *short read*. Short reads don't *necessarily* mean that you're at the end of the channel, use `chan eof` and `chan blocked` to find out more (especially if you get the special case of a zero-length read). Being blocked might also not mean that you're at the end of a message within a higher-level protocol; more data may be coming, but it hasn't reached the OS yet (which is why you need a framing protocol on top of TCP; websockets are one such framing protocol).

Counting the data is easy: `string length`.

**tl;dr:** In *non-blocking* mode, the maximum amount that `read` of a binary channel can return is whatever is currently in the input buffers plus whatever is obtained from *one* non-blocking read of the file descriptor. In *blocking* mode, `read` will wait until the requested amount of data is available or definitely not available (end-of-file), performing multiple reads of the file descriptor if necessary.

Comment: Remember: in Tcl, binary data is just a string. There's very little special about it (the implementation of strings hides the size of types involved, and you should ignore it if you're not directly using the C API).